# General organic chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point

What is the correct order of boiling points of the following compounds ?
1) butanol
2)butanal
3)butanoic acid

Comment: It takes like a minute to google that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boiling points depends on strength of intermolecular interaction. In case of butanol and butanoic acid there is H bonding which is a stronger intermolecular attractive force. Further butanoic acid remain in dimeric form so there is more extent of H bonding. So order of boiling point is butanoic acid > butanol > butanal.